# ASP.Net - working around MaxHttpCollectionKeys

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a huge table, the number of cells can reach a little above 1000. All of the cells contain a textbox. A cell is implemented as a user control. There are validation constraints, around a 100 cells can be filled at any given time, not an exact number, but way below 1000, guaranteed. When I post this form, I hit the MaxHttpCollectionKeys limit, because the empty fields are posted back as well.

Because of the nature if this application, overriding this limit in web.config is highly undesirable, although it's better than nothing. Is there a smart way to not include the textboxes in a postback by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best solution. Create all the text fields without a name attribute. This way they will not be posted back ever. This is exactly the trick I needed. During the postback, save the text field values in JSON and put it in a hidden field, this will be posted back automatically. Then the normal page lifecycle, including postbacks can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is another work-around using JavaScript.  You could scroll through the textboxes and create a json object of the changes.  Post this back and then just refresh the table.

What is implied here is that you do not post back via a normal button at all.